# NVDA reader reads the source of an image in img tag - in IE Browser Only

Tags: html, internet-explorer, screen-readers, alt, nvda

On mouse-over on an image in IE browser, the NVDA screen reader reads the entire source of the image file along with alt text and title, for example:

> Smiley http://blog.smiley.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/High-Res-image.jpg

How do I avoid this from happening? I want the screen reader to read only the alt text and title.