# How to read alt text using a screen reader in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, accessibility, nvda

I am using NVDA and I want to know why my `img` elements alt text are not being read by the screen reader. By being read I mean as in *listening* to the screen reader telling the alt text contents back to me.

*Good to know*: every other browser (Chrome, FireFox, Safari, others) have had no issues doing this, except for IE.

I have the following dummy HTML code to share with you.

```
<img id="sample_image" src="http://placehold.it//100x100" type="image" alt="An example image" tabindex="0"/>
```

For your information: `tabindex="0"` is in place so I can use keyboard focus on it, it matters to me.

I have read the documents on the matter of image alt text in E, image tag accessibility in IE, among other inquiries. Sadly I have hit a roadblock and I am stuck trying to figure out what is wrong with IE.

Any feedback as to why this is the case would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Open **Internet Options**, switch to tab **Advanced** and check the *Accessibility* option *Always expand ALT text for images*.

This is recommended on Microsoft article [Accessibility in Internet Explorer 9](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/products/ie9/) for screen readers. This setting is recognized by all versions of Internet Explorer.

You may need to uncheck option *Show pictures* under *Multimedia* also on tab **Advanced** of the **Internet Options** as the Microsoft page [Accessibility in Internet Explorer 11](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/products/ie11/) additionally recommends.

I have this option also enabled although not using a screen reader to get the alternate text displayed as tooltip.

Comment: I am not by my computer until tomorrow, but I tried doing this and it didn't do anything for the speech portion. I wonder if this has anything to do with the screen reader itself more than IE

Comment: Back to my computer sorry for the long wait, so I did all your suggestions (including some extra from what I found in the linked articles) but that still didn't work. For some reason IE refuses to read **in speech that I can listen to** the alt text for the image. Unless you have any further suggestions I will just have to accept the fact that IE sucks

Comment: I searched in www for web pages about NVDA and Internet Explorer and there were and are still known issues. The [NVDA news page](http://www.nvaccess.org/category/news/) contains several notes about Internet Explorer related fixes. Do you use release 2015.4 of NVDA? Interesting is question [NVDA reader reads the source of an image in img tag - in IE Browser Only](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30796844/3074564) because this means it is possible that alternate text is read by screen reader using IE. Which __doctype__ do you have specified in your HTML file? Using quirks mode could be an issue.

Comment: I have `<!DOCTYPE html>` as my doctype and do not use quirks mode, you can also see this question **[How to prevent screen reader from reading src attribute from img tag in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33112473/1046690)** related to the one you linked, but I did not find an answer through it. It all leads me to believe that the team that works with IE or at NVDA (or both) need to get their job done in terms of accessibility for these issues. If you disagree and think it's something else, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `aria-label` attribute (conjointly with the `alt` attribute).

Comment: I will on Monday, not by my computer until then, you know happy 2016 and everything :-)